# Which GLSL versions to use for maximum compatibility

Tags: opengl, glsl

**Update 2**

I think my question might really be, "How do I write OpenGL code that will work on any machine that supports at least OpenGL 2.0?"    Bearing in mind that a compatibility profile is not guaranteed to be available.

**Update 1**:

Rabbid76 is suggesting to either use a specific core profile or use a compatibility profile.

The compatibility profile isn't guaranteed to be available so let's say I choose to use OpenGL 3.3 core profile as the minimum requirement.  Wouldn't it still be the case that I would have to write three different versions of the GLSL shaders?

- 3.30  For OpenGL 3.3
- 4.00  For OpenGL 4.0
- 4.10  For OpenGL 4.1 and onwards

From reading around people seem to assume that GLSL 3.30 works on OpenGL 3.3 and all later versions, but that doesn't seem to be guaranteed by any spec before OpenGL 4.2.

Is this right?

---

**Original question:**

I've read various versions of the OpenGL spec I can't see any useful guarantees about backwards compatibility of GLSL support.

Here's what I've deduced from the specs:

- OpenGL 2.0 supports GLSL 1.10
- OpenGL 2.2 supports GLSL 1.20
- OpenGL 3.0 supports GLSL 1.10, 1.20 & 1.30
- OpenGL 3.1 supports GLSL 1.30 & 1.40
- OpenGL 3.2 supports GLSL 1.40 & 1.50
- OpenGL 3.3 supports GLSL 3.30
- OpenGL 4.0 supports GLSL 4.00
- OpenGL 4.1 supports GLSL 4.10
- OpenGL 4.2 supports GLSL 4.20 and all versions back to 1.40
- From OpenGL 4.2 onwards it seems that support back to GLSL version 1.40 is guaranteed.

Note that guarantees of backwards compatibility are quite rare until OpenGL 4.2!

So if I want to ship an application which supports all versions of OpenGL back to 2.0 I would need to write every shader in the following versions:

- 1.10  For OpenGL 2.0
- 1.20  For OpenGL 2.2 & 3.0
- 1.40  For OpenGL 3.1, 3.2 & 4.2 onwards
- 3.30  For OpenGL 3.3
- 4.00  For OpenGL 4.0
- 4.10  For OpenGL 4.1

That's six versions of each shader!   Is there an easier way to make GLSL portable?

Why are the specs so unhelpful in this regard?

Comment: Use a compatibility profile. e.g.: [OpenGL 4.6 Compatibility Profile Specification - 1.6.1 OpenGL Shading Language](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf): *"The compatibility profile of OpenGL 4.6 is also guaranteed to support all previous versions of the OpenGL Shading Language back to version 1.10."*

Comment: But I can't assume the user will have OpenGL 4.6.  They might have only have 4.1, so I need to provide a GLSL 4.10 shader.  They might only have 4.0, so I need to provide 4.00, etc..

Comment: This applies to all compatibility profiles. (I only used 4.6 as an example)

Comment: I would love this to be true.  But I can't see it in 4.1 specs and earlier.  For example https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec41.core.pdf
As I said in the question, the backwards compatibility promise only appears from 4.2 onwards.

Comment: You refer to a core profile specification. See [OpenGL specification - Khronos OpenGL registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php)

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you referred to a compatibility spec.  Ok, but compatibility profile isn't guaranteed to be available.

Comment: If you want to use a core profile, you must specify the minimum hardware requirements for your application. "backwards compatibility" is only guaranteed with a compatibility profile. There is no point to guarantee backwards compatibility with a core profile.

Comment: But what if I only want to use features from OpenGL 2.0 / GLSL 1.10?  I can't use a core profile because it wouldn't support it and I can't use a compatibility profile because it might not exist.  I'm not trying to argue I just don't see how anyone can write code that's guaranteed to work under these specs.

Comment: OpenGL 2.0 has no core profile. Each compatibility profile supports all instructions and shaders form OpenGL 2.0.

Comment: But the point still stands. On a given user's machine the driver might not have support for OpenGL 2.0, and it might not have a compatibility profile either.  So my code wouldn't work.

Comment: @AILien: "*On a given user's machine the driver might not have support for OpenGL 2.0*" If you're writing against OpenGL 2.0, then *that's what you write against*. "*it might not have a compatibility profile either*" There are no profiles in 2.0; it's just OpenGL. OpenGL 2.0 is compatible with all versions of OpenGL up to 3.1, and then all version of the compatibility profile higher than that. If they don't support GL 2.0, or the compatibility profile, your code won't work anyway.

Comment: Let me put it this way:  "How do I write OpenGL code that will work on any machine that supports at least OpenGL 2.0?"

Comment: @AILien: The only system I know about that supports OpenGL 4.* but not 2.0 are Macs. And in this case you have to use a core profile, which automatically makes it impossible to run the code on machines that do not support core profile. Unless you write specific rendering backends for specific targets, there is no way to get what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Wouldn't it still be the case that I would have to write three different versions of the GLSL shaders?

No.

In order to use the core 3.3 profile, you must ask the WGL/GLX/EGL system that creates OpenGL to give you what you asked for. That is, it must give you core 3.3 or any later implementation that is compatible with core 3.3.

In order for an implementation to be compatible with 3.3, it must accept GLSL of version 3.30. So if you request a core 3.3 context, and you get a valid context of a higher version, that implementation *will* support 3.30 shaders.

That is, just because a particular standard version doesn't mandate compatibility with older shader versions does not mean the implementation won't provide it.

> How do I write OpenGL code that will work on any machine that supports at least OpenGL 2.0?

You can't. At least, not without distinct codepaths.

Some implementations do not support the compatibility profile at all. As such, if you do not code against at least GL 3.2 (or whatever their lowest core implementation version is), your code won't be able to work on their implementations. It just isn't possible.

Some implementations have a GL 2.x implementation as a fallback, but have a higher core profile implementation without the compatibility profile. You can access the fallback with your 2.0 code, but no extensions or core features for the newer stuff.

It should also be noted that most implementations that are limited to OpenGL 2.0 are extremely old and likely quite bug-prone. You would have to test your code extremely broadly in order to know whether or not it would work on a bunch of them. So unless you have the resources to buy and test on dozens of outdated Intel integrated chipsets, it's best to pick a version that's more recent.

Comment: This is very helpful. Could you clarify this statement: "As such, if you do not code against at least GL 3.2, you cannot run code written against GL 2.0 on such implementations."  It seems self contradicting.